# What is the real K-theory of the spheres?

Tags: topological-k-theory

In many sources one finds a computation of the complex topological K-theory of the spheres $S^n$, but the real theory $KO(S^n)$ is usually not computed. Maybe it can be read off some more advanced stuff, but I am unable to do so. I would like to see a computation of, say $KO(S^2)$.
Can somebody give me a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computation of these groups is an immediate consequence of real Bott periodicity. Namely, by representability you have
$$
    \widetilde{KO}(S^n) \cong [S^n, BO \times \mathbb{Z}]_* \cong \begin{cases}
    [S^n, BO]_* = \pi_n(BO) & \text{if }n > 0 \\
    \mathbb{Z} & \text{if } n = 0
\end{cases}
$$
and since $\pi_n(BO) \cong \pi_{n - 1}(O)$ you get to read off that
\begin{align}
    \widetilde{KO}(S^0) &\cong \mathbb{Z} \\
    \widetilde{KO}(S^1) &\cong \mathbb{Z}/2 \\
    \widetilde{KO}(S^2) &\cong \mathbb{Z}/2 \\
    \widetilde{KO}(S^3) &\cong 0 \\
    \widetilde{KO}(S^4) &\cong \mathbb{Z} \\
    \widetilde{KO}(S^5) &\cong 0 \\
    \widetilde{KO}(S^6) &\cong 0 \\
    \widetilde{KO}(S^7) &\cong 0 \\
\end{align}
with $\widetilde{KO}(S^{8k + i}) \cong \widetilde{KO}(S^i)$ accounting for all remaining groups. This table you can also find [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/KO-theory), and the Wikipedia pages for [topological $K$-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_K-theory) and [Bott periodicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bott_periodicity_theorem), too, are pretty useful. For a proper mathematical text, Karoubi's "$K$-Theory―An Introduction" gives a proof of the periodicity theorem, but be warned that it's neither easy nor short.